# How to resolve post method which continues loading in postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, http, postman

I'm new in Express.js,MongoDb and mongoose, I have created HTTP request methods, but when running the Post method, nothing done (nothing saved in the database), and postman continues  loading and it stops only when I cancel.
I want to know what's wrong in my code, thank you .

this is my routes file 'department.js':

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Department = require("../models/department")

router.get("/v1/departments", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const departments = await Department.find({ isDeleted: false })
        if (!departments) {
            return res.status(404).send()
        }
        res.status(200).send()
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
});

router.get("/v1/department/:id", async (req, res) => {
    //test if the department exist => by id
    const _id = req.params._id
    try {
        const depatment = await Department.findByid(_id, { isDeleted: false })
        if (!depatment) {
            return res.status(404).send()
        }
        res.status(200).send(depatment)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
});

router.post("/department", async (req, res) => {
    const department = new Department(req.body) //this param is for testing the post methode by sending request from postman
    try {
        await department.save()
        // res.status(201).send(department)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
});

router.put("/v1/department/:id", async (req, res) => {
    //updates , allowedUpdates ,isValideOperations : those constants are used for checking if the updated fields exists or not !
    //especially useful when testing the put method using postman 
    const updates = Object.keys(req.body)
    const allowedUpdates = ['name', 'email']
    const isValideOperations = updates.every((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update)) //isValideOperations return true if all keys exists
    if (!isValideOperations) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid updates' })
    }
    try {
        const _id = req.params.id
        const department = await Department.findByIdAndUpdate(_id)
        if (!department) {
            return res.status(404).send()
        }
        res.send(department)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
})

//Safe delete by updating the field isDeleted to true
router.delete('/v1/department/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const _id = req.params.id
        const department = await Department.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { isDeleted: true })
        if (!department) {
            return res.status(400).send()
        }
        res.status(200).send(department)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

And this is the Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require('validator')


const Department = mongoose.model('Department', {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
    ,
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate(value) {
            if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error('Invalid email!')
            }
        }
    }
    ,
    createdBy: {
        type: String,
        default: 'SYS_ADMIN'
    }
    ,
    updatedBy: {
        type: String,
        default: 'SYS_ADMIN'
    }
    ,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
        // ,
        // default: Date.getDate()
    }
    ,
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date
        // ,
        // default: Date.getDate()
    },
    isDeleted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
})

module.exports = Department

this is Index.js (the main file)

const express = require("express");
const app = express()
const departmentRouter = require("../src/routes/department")


app.use(express.json())
app.use(departmentRouter)

//app.use('/', require('./routes/department'))


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;//local machine port 3000
app.listen(port, () => (`Server running on local machine port ${port} `));
```

Comment: Your `router.post("/department", ...)` route does not send any response if the `.save()` succeeds. The client will just sit there waiting for a response.

Comment: but in my case, Postman still loading, and ,nothing happened in the database (nothing added)

Comment: @jfriend00 any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to add '/v1' in this route. it should be

```
router.post("/v1/department", async (req, res) => {
    const department = new Department(req.body) //this param is for testing the post methode by sending request from postman
    try {
        await department.save()
        // res.status(201).send(department)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to send a response, uncomment your response code

Comment: do you only get this with the post method or other methods too? and just for once try the other method of creating a document.
const department = await Department.create(req.body); and try to send a json response like 
res.status(201).json({ department})

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to get a response in Postman (or in an API call in general), you must actually send back a response, whether it's with `sendFile, render, json, send, etc`. These methods all call the built-in `res.end` which sends back data. However you commented out `res.send` which is the reason

Comment: I have the same problem after uncomment  // res.status(201).send(department)